# Add request header after successfull authentication in Spring

Tags: spring-security

I have an app where authentication of JWT token is done using spring security custom filter. The configuration looks as below to invoke the customer filter which does the authentication.

```
    <security:http entry-point-ref="authenticationEntryPoint">
      <security:custom-filter after="BASIC_AUTH_FILTER" ref="TokenValidationFilter" />
      <security:session-management>
        <security:concurrency-control max-sessions="1" />
      </security:session-management>
      <security:csrf disabled="true"/>
      <security:anonymous enabled="false"/>
    </security:http>
```

I extended AbstractAuthenticationProcessingFilter class and implemented TokenValidationFilter and able to authenticate the token received in request header. After successfull authentication,  I want to call an another external API and get few values and append them in current request header.   AbstractAuthenticationProcessingFilter class offers successfulAuthentication method as callback where I can do the external call and modify the request header. But I want to have a separate class or filter which needs to be invoked after successfull authentication for code maintainablility. Please let me know whether Spring offers any option for this. I am newbie to Spring and searched multiple sites but could not figure out how to approach this. Any suggestion would be much helpful.Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Please look into [`AuthenticationSuccessHandler`](https://docs.spring.io/spring-security/site/docs/current/api/org/springframework/security/web/authentication/AuthenticationSuccessHandler.html).

It allows you to control the response when login is successful.

Here is an example:

```
@Configuration
@EnableWebSecurity
public class WebSecurityConfig extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {
 
    ...
     
    @Override
    protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        http.authorizeRequests()
            ...
            .formLogin()
                .loginPage("/login")
                .usernameParameter("email")
                .permitAll()
                .successHandler(new AuthenticationSuccessHandler() {
 
                    @Override
                    public void onAuthenticationSuccess(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response,
                            Authentication authentication) throws IOException, ServletException {
                        // You have access to request, respnse, and authentication object containing all the user details.
                        response.addHeader("Header_Name", value);
                    }
                })
            ...
    }
 
}
```